# Override click.Option to prompt for value only if it is not present in a config file

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am trying to write a custom class that will read from a **JSON** config file and prompt for value only if the value is not present in the file using python **click's option** decorator.

This is my CLIConfig class that will fetch the required data from the config.json file. How can this be enhanced to integrate with click.Option?

```
class CLIConfig():
    def __init__(self, source_app_name):
        self.source_app_name = source_app_name
                        
    def gitlab_access_token(self):
        if 'scm' in self.config_dict and 'accessToken' in self.config_dict['scm']:
            return self.config_dict['scm']['accessToken']
        return None
    
    def group_id(self):
        if 'scm' in self.config_dict and 'groupId' in self.config_dict['scm']:
            return self.config_dict['scm']['groupId']
        return None
            
    def microservice_path(self):
        if 'scm' in self.config_dict and 'microservice' in self.config_dict['scm']:
            return self.config_dict['scm']['microservice'].get('localPath', None)
        return None
    
    def terraform_path(self):
        if 'scm' in self.config_dict and 'terraform' in self.config_dict['scm']:
            return self.config_dict['scm']['terraform'].get('localPath', None)
        return None
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.f = open(pathlib.Path.home().joinpath(f".{self.source_app_name}", "config.json"), mode='r')
        try:
            self.config_dict = json.load(self.f)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            self.config_dict = {}
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        self.f.close()
```

On the first run, it should be able to write the option to the config file and on subsequent runs, it should not prompt for the value anymore

This is the structure of my CLI

```
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    """Root level of CLI
    """
   pass

@click.command(name='setup', help='Setup CLI')
@click.argument('source_app_name', default=pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).name)
@click.option('--microservice_path', prompt='Enter the local repository location for microservices', type=click.Path())
@click.option('--terraform_path', prompt='Enter the local repository location for terraform', type=click.Path())
@click.option('--private_token', hide_input=True, prompt='Provide GitLab API Token')
@click.pass_context
def setup(ctx, microservice_path, terraform_path, private_token):
    some logic here
```

Requirement is almost identical to [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999396/perform-different-parent-command-actions-if-specific-subcommand-is-called)